# Return all time today spent on tasks that include a particular tag

Tags: org-mode

As the title. I have come *so close* but can't get past this last hurdle.

The below returns all time today that has been spent on headings where the tag is 'billable'. However it fails when there are also other tags. I've tried to replace string= with a test for the string containing billable, but for some reason it fails.

You can see some of my attempts commented out below.

Tia.

```
(defun my-broken-function ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((files (org-agenda-files))
        (total 0))
    (org-agenda-prepare-buffers files)
    (dolist (file files)
      (with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting file)
        (setq total (+ total (org-clock-sum-today (lambda ()
            (string= (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS") ":billable:")
            ;; (string-match  ":billable:" (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS"))
            ;; (not (not (string-match-p (regexp-quote "billable") (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS"))))
            ))))))
    (message (number-to-string total))
    ))
```

Comment: `org-entry-get` may return `nil` which is not a string, so it will cause any string functions to barf. Try replacing any such call with `(or (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS") "")`, effectively replacing the `nil` with the empty string. The `string-match` implementation should  then work. If it does not, edit your question and **add the error that you get** - don't just tell us there is some error. And set `debug-on-error` so that errors will generate backtraces - then post the backtrace.

Comment: Thanks for pointer, and thanks for the tip on useful info to include in questions. This is all still new to me, but I'll remember that for the future. 
What you suggested worked, I'll answer the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per NickD's comment:

"org-entry-get may return nil which is not a string, so it will cause any string functions to barf. Try replacing any such call with (or (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS") ""), effectively replacing the nil with the empty string."

What worked is replacing the ninth line with:

```
(string-match  ":billable:" (or (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS") ""))
```